# Automate trapcode sound keys in after effects

Tags: c#, .net, automation, extendscript, after-effects

I work with after effects alot and i would need to automate a plugin called Trapcode Sound Keys
and i did some research and unfortunately this cannot be done with ExtendScript(the built in scripts for after effects) as far as i know.
The Script/Program would need to apply the keyframes as shown below in the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvmPK.png

So my question is can this be done in C# with some gui automation or somehow in ExtendScript
Also would it be possible to do the automation so the user doesnt see any window

Answer (score 0):

It's true that there is no API access to Trapcode's SoundKeys.  If you use GUI Automation, you can use [AutoIt scripting language](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to direct the mouse cursor to specific co-ordinates relative to the AE Window and then programatically invoke "clicks".  The problem here, of course, is that AE's internal workspace layout would need to be remain in the same exact size and position each time you ran the script.  You would also need to devise some method by which the AutoIt script timed the clicks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did got it to work but not with AutoIt, i managed to do it in C# because my main program was based in it. I basically launched after affects and timed clicks a the point where the button was and then used extendscript to the rest